# Get a value from a multidimensional array Wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I've this array :

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'agence',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'dinan')
            )
        )
    );
```

I want to pick the value 'dinan' from this array,
Thanks for the reply !

Comment: where is `WP_QUERY`  and what is the output ?

Answer (score 2):

The way to pick from that array:

```
$tmp = $args['tax_query']['terms'][0];
```

Comment: *this?* Why do you have to ask OP?! OP has asked a question not you. And if something is unclear use comments for clarification!

Comment: @Rizier123 the _this?_ is more retorical as "is this the answer you are looking for?" But I can change it, if you don't like it.

Comment: This works only in PHP 5.4+. Selecting items in array like this will not work on PHP 5.3 which is still a very commonly used version on most hosts.

Comment: @gusfune could you explain why? On php 5.3.10 it works for me and I never heard of problems with it befor.

Comment: @gusfune what excatly is a PHP 5.4+ feature? I found nothin in the manu about that.

Comment: Accessing multi-dimensional array items like that is NOT php 5.4, you are thinking of when they are added to a method or function.